# Input losing focus after first entered symbol

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have authorization component where users use their phone numbers as login. And problem that after entering one symbol (doesn't matter letter or number) `input` loses focus and user needs to click it again to enter further.
`UPD:` Forgot to mention that there are 3 inputs. At the beginning there will be first input, when its empty. And after typing first number it will be replaced by second or third input depending which country user is. For certain country it will be replaced by input with +7 prefix, for another one with +9

html:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="phone"
             *ngIf="isPhoneEmpty()"
             class="phone-input m-b-50"
             id="phone-input"
             type="text"
             name="phone"
             minlength=18
             placeholder="Phone number"
             required>

    <input [(ngModel)]="phone"
             *ngIf="checkCountry() && !isPhoneEmpty()"
             class="phone-input m-b-50"
           id="phone-input"
             type="text"
             name="phone"
             minlength=18
             placeholder="Phone number"
             prefix="+7"
             mask=" (000) 000-00-00"
           autofocus
             required>

      <input [(ngModel)]="phone"
             *ngIf="!checkCountry() && !isPhoneEmpty()"
             class="phone-input m-b-50"
             id="phone-input"
             type="text"
             name="phone"
             placeholder="PhoneNumber"
             prefix="+996"
             mask=" (000) 000-000"
             autofocus
             required>
```

component:

```
import { HostListener} from '@angular/core';
phone: string;

checkCountry() {
    return this.currentCountry.name === this.countryList[0].name;
  }
isPhoneEmpty() {
    return this.phone === '';
  }

@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    const numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

    if (numbers.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
     this._documentRef.getElementById('phone-input').focus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does it still happen if you remove the `*ngIf`?

Comment: Try changing it to type='tel'

Comment: @Reactgular added more info

Comment: Have you looked into using a reactive form to give you greater control of the form controls? That would also allow you to use the `valueChanges` Observables of each input. Accessing the DOM directly is an Angular counter-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have 3 inputs and you toggle between those 3 with *ngIf. When the phone is empty you show the first input, and as soon as you type something the *ngIf of the first one will be false and then the first input will not be rendered and instead the second one will render, this is why you lose the focus on the first input.

I would suggest you only have one input field, why do you need three?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know what country the phone number is from. Just from the first number? Or has the user already given you that information?

If you already have the information use that to show the desired input when the page is loaded and not when the user starts typing. Right now the input changes after the first keypress is causing the loss of focus.

Comment: In the same page I have a ```select``` with 2 options / countries

Comment: @Massaget Then I would change the shown input based on that select. This could lead to another problem. If the user inputs the phone and then changes the country. But since you are using the same ngModel for all the inputs just the mask and prefix should change. Try it out.